# pybind mask values of py::array

Tags: c++, numpy, pybind11

It is quite easy to use a mask array to get values from another array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=np.float32)
mask = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1], dtype=np.bool)

print(arr[mask])
# would ofc get me [2, 3, 5]
```

I want to mimic this inside pybind11. The simplest way I found is this:

```
static py::array_t<float, py::array::c_style> maskMyArray(
    py::array_t<float, py::array::c_style | py::array::forcecast>& arr,
    py::array_t<bool, py::array::c_style | py::array::forcecast>& mask
) {
    auto arr_ptr = static_cast<const float*>(arr.request().ptr);
    auto mask_ptr = static_cast<const bool*>(mask.request().ptr);

    std::vector<float> masked_values;
    masked_values.reserve(1000);  // I have tried adjusting this pre-allocation

    // copy only values where mask is True
    for (std::uint32_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        if (mask_ptr[i]) {
            masked_values.push_back(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    // copy masked_values into a py::array
    std::size_t M = masked_values.size();
    std::vector<std::size_t> output_sz{M};
    py::array_t<float, py::array::c_style> masked_array(output_sz);
    auto masked_array_ptr = static_cast<float*>(masked_array.request().ptr);
    std::memcpy(masked_array_ptr, masked_values.data(), sizeof(float) * M);
    
    return masked_array;
}
```

After some profiling, I have seen that the `for` loop is pretty slow (as compared to native numpy masking). I feel like I am missing the plot here.

I have noticed that I can do something like the following - but I am not sure if it would be faster:

```
    py::detail::item_accessor arr_mask_iter = arr[mask];

    for (auto it = arr_mask_iter.begin(); it != arr_mask_iter.end(); ++it) {
        masked_values.push_back(it->cast<float>());
    }
```

I am not too familiar with the `item_accessor` and documentation/examples for it pretty sparse. But it is faster than the first solution - but it is still not as fast as native numpy masking. Any ideas how I can make this faster?

Comment: One immediate improvement to the current code can be `int size = std::accumulate(mask.begin(), mask.end(), (int)0);` and then `masked_values.reserve(size);`. Otherwise, the for loop looks to me like the fastest solution. You could also try to implement a zip iterator, zip 2 ranges masked_values and mask, and then apply `std::remove_if`, which will shift unmasked values to the end of the range. Not sure if faster though, because `remove_if` is also O(N).

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the fastest. You can apparently create a new array directly from the `item_accessor` - it gives you the masked array directly:

```
py::detail::item_accessor arr_mask_iter = arr[mask];

py::array_t<float, py::array::c_style | py::array::forcecast> arr_mask(arr_mask_iter);
```